# Unusually long Pig job start time

Tags: apache-pig

A pig script (not particularly more complex than any others I have built) before the job starts it seems to loop on this for a long time:

```
2013-10-08 10:46:07,655 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 10
2013-10-08 10:46:07,659 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 10
2013-10-08 10:46:09,168 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 10
2013-10-08 10:46:09,168 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 10
2013-10-08 10:46:11,381 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 10
2013-10-08 10:46:11,381 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 10
2013-10-08 10:46:13,875 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 10
2013-10-08 10:46:13,875 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 10
2013-10-08 10:46:16,303 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 10
```

It repeats the above for around 4 minutes when usually this step is completed in seconds. I have not been able to identify the cause - other than removing parts of the script but the issue does not seem to be caused by any particular part of the script. I have other scripts as complex as this one and I have not had this problem. What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain without more information, but it appears that pig is waiting for your cluster's JobTracker to start running the underlying Map/Reduce jobs generated by your script.  There are numerious reasons why this could be happening such as running on a shared cluster which has run out of resources.  You'll most likely have to look at your cluster's JobTracker and/or TaskTrackers to know the exact reason.